# Alternatives for marshaling c++ unmanaged code to c# managed code

Tags: c#, c++, frontend, backend, marshalling

I am making a C++ application and trying to create a GUI front-end for it in C#, and communicate between the two.
My initial idea was compiling the c++ back-end as a DLL and using its functions by importing it to the front-end and using P/Invoke, but I ran into a problem:

My unmanaged C++ classes are using generic types (such as std::vector or std::list) and cannot be marshaled to C# managed code (at least according to my knowledge).

One of my classes in C++:

```cpp
class Album
{
public:
    Album() = default;
    Album(int ownerId, const std::string& name);
    Album(int ownerId, const std::string& name, const std::string& creationTime);

    const std::string& getName() const;
    void setName(const std::string& name);

    int getOwnerId() const;
    void setOwner(int userId);

    std::string getCreationDate() const;
    void setCreationDate(const std::string& creationTime);
    void setCreationDateNow();

    bool doesPictureExists(const std::string& name) const;
    void addPicture(const Picture& picture);
    void removePicture(const std::string& pictureName);

    Picture getPicture(const std::string& name) const;
    std::list<Picture> getPictures() const;

    void untagUserInAlbum(int userId);
    void tagUserInAlbum(int userId);

    void untagUserInPicture(int userId, const std::string& pictureName);
    void tagUserInPicture(int userId, const std::string& pictureName);

    bool operator==(const Album& other) const;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& strOut, const Album& album);

private:
    int m_ownerId { 0 };
    std::string m_name;
    std::string m_creationDate;
    std::list<Picture> m_pictures;
};
```

What are (if exists) some ways to "bypass" the issue with marshaling a class object containing a generic type? If there aren't any, what are good alternatives of communication between C# front-end to C++ back-end which I can use instead of P/Invoke?

Comment: You can't use pinvoke.  Google "c++/cli wrapper tutorial" to get ahead.

Comment: It seems that you're looking for a way to exchange data only (no need to run unmanaged code)? What about using some IPC mechanism such [Shared Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files?redirectedfrom=MSDN)?

Comment: @WillyK. I do need to run unmanaged code. I need to call functions that returns objects such as an Album, which is detailed in the question.